# Blue screen - BCCode: 7F

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I've recently bought a refurbished Toshiba Satellite A660 11M and I get the blue screen of death appearing fairly frequently now, and I can't seem to work out why or how to prevent/cure it.
Firstly I thought it was due to Zone Alarm from what I read on the net, but then I thought it was a memory issue after it crashed whilst I was running Memtest. But after I ran Memtest a second time, it completed without any errors...

Here are my computer specs -

> Toshiba Satellite A660 11M
>   500 GB hard disk
>   4 GB RAM
>   Windows 7 Premium
>   Nvidia GeForce GT 330M

and here is more info regarding the crashes I keep getting -

```
Problem signature: Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
  Locale ID: 2057

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode: 7f
  BCP1: 0000000000000008
  BCP2: 0000000080050033
  BCP3: 00000000000006F8
  BCP4: FFFFF80003040EC0
  OS Version: 6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product: 768_1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do note, that there is no such thing as "memtest completing fine". Memtest needs to be run for days through to catch hiding issues, and even then you can't be 100% certain. 24 hours is pretty much a minimum for calling memories "most likely OK".

Answer (score 1):

If it crashed while running memtest, most likely you have a defective memory module, if you have more than one module installed, you need to remove all but one, and run memtest again, let it run overnight if needed, test each module separately to find the bad one.

On rare occasions just removing and reinstalling the memory modules a few times can cure it.

> 0x0000007F: UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP
>
> One of three types of problems occurred in kernel-mode: (1) Hardware failures. (2) Software problems. (3) A bound trap (i.e., a condition that the kernel is not allowed to have or intercept). Hardware failures are the most common cause (many dozen KB articles exist for this error referencing specific hardware failures) and, of these, **memory hardware failures are the most common**.

http://aumha.org/a/stop.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559244(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact error. In my case the memory was not compatible to the second one.
As you can see by the other answers already submitted, check your memory and replace them if necessary.